# jQuery Sales Tax

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a function (see below) that calculates a 7.5% sales tax. Now I need help doing the following:

- Have totalTax() take in 2 arguments
  one for the price and one for the
  tax.
- On submit (use the onSubmit event
  handler to call this function) have
  the function process the price and
  the tax by manipulating the arguments
  you passed in.
- Have the sales tax on the page update
  dynamically with what ever the sales
  tax is that you defined for the
  function 
  7.5 percent sales tax:

  Instead of using .innerHTML use
  jQuery to access these document
  elements and write to them:

  ```
     document.getElementById('requestedAmount' ).innerHTML = priceInput;  
     document.getElementById('requestedTax' ).innerHTML = salesTax;   
     document.getElementById('requestedTotal' ).innerHTML = totalAmount;
  ```

Original Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$().ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#inputForm").validate(); 
    $("#priceInput").priceFormat({
    prefix: '',
    limit: 5,
    centsLimit: 2
}); 
});

function totalTax(){
  var priceInput = document.getElementById( 'priceInput' ).value;
  var salesTax = Math.round(((priceInput / 100) * 7.5)*100)/100;
  var totalAmount = (priceInput*1) + (salesTax * 1);

  document.getElementById( 'requestedAmount' ).innerHTML = priceInput;
  document.getElementById( 'requestedTax' ).innerHTML = salesTax;
  document.getElementById( 'requestedTotal' ).innerHTML = totalAmount;
}
</script>

<body>
<form class="cmxform" id="inputForm" method="get" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="priceInput">Enter the price: </label>
    <input id="priceInput" name="name" class="required"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="totalTax();"/>
  </p>
</form>
<div>Entered price:
  <p id="requestedAmount"></p>
</div>
<div>7.5 percent sales tax:
  <p id="requestedTax"></p>
</div>
<div>Total:
  <p id="requestedTotal"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: hope you are doing this server side also, someone could change the script to calculate negative tax :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for your need of converting it to jquery is here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // validate the comment form when it is submitted
    $("#inputForm").validate(); 
    $("#priceInput").priceFormat({
    prefix: '',
    limit: 5,
    centsLimit: 2
}); 
});

function totalTax(){
  var priceInput = parseFloat(($("#priceInput").var());//document.getElementById( 'priceInput' ).value;
  var salesTax = Math.round(((priceInput / 100) * 7.5)*100)/100;
  var totalAmount = (priceInput*1) + (salesTax * 1);

  $('#requestedAmount' ).html(priceInput) ;
  $( '#requestedTax' ).html(salesTax);
  $( '#requestedTotal' ).html(totalAmount);
}
</script>

<body>
<form class="cmxform" id="inputForm" method="get" action="">
  <p>
    <label for="priceInput">Enter the price: </label>
    <input id="priceInput" name="name" class="required"/>
  </p>
  <p>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="totalTax();"/>
  </p>
</form>
<div>Entered price:
  <p id="requestedAmount"></p>
</div>
<div>7.5 percent sales tax:
  <p id="requestedTax"></p>
</div>
<div>Total:
  <p id="requestedTotal"> </p>
</div>
```